# How does this anchor tag close the popup?

Tags: html

I just went through this tutorial: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/ - to gain an understanding of modal popups with HTML5 + CSS3. What I would like to know is how the anchor tag is able to close the popup:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads,  or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I changed the href to just "#" and it still works so I'm guessing that by virtue of targeting another element, the popup loses its `target` state in CSS and its opacity is set back to 0?

Here is a Codepen from one of the commenters: http://codepen.io/petebot/pen/DBvKj - its not the exact code but conveys the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using the `:target` CSS3 selector. As long as `#openModal` is the URL fragment, it matches the ID of the modal, and then the styles upon it are applied. When you click the close link, the fragment changes, and the styles no longer apply, so it gets closed.

The modal will only remain open while the target is `#openModal`, even if you were to change it manually.

Comment: How would one use javascript to click `href="#close"`?